# Why does this computer only work when it's tipped forward?

Tags: freeze, crash

Last night my girlfriend’s computer was having some overheating issues, so I took out the graphics card, disassembled it, and cleaned all the dust out. Since then, the computer only works when it’s leaned forward as pictured below.

If I tip it back up, it immediately freezes. If I try to turn it on when it’s sitting upright, it just won’t start. What could be causing this?

[image: haunted computer]

Comment: When removing the card and "dissembling," did you remove all the parts out of the PC, or did you dissemble the video card? If you removed all PC contents, it sounds like you are having a grounding issue and when the PC is sitting flat, it is shorting out and freezing - I suggest powering down, removing all cables and possibly re-seating the motherboard and ensuring it is properly aligned on the standoffs

Comment: Sounds to me like 1) CPU not fully seated/pasted; and 2) the CPU fan doesn't spin/spin fast enough when the case is upright.

Comment: @mikeDiglio I just disassembled the graphics card, not the rest of the computer

Comment: @SaintWacko sounds like a bad connection when you re-assembled the card then - connectors are not sitting right and causing a short which is causing the PC to freeze/not turn on

Comment: I've tried reaching in and wiggling the graphics card while it's tipped like that, and it stays on. I had figured it was a loose connection

Comment: Out of interest what made you think the original problem was due to the computer overheating?

Comment: @ramhound I had already been worried about that because of the enclosed space, and then it began just turning off occasionally. A monitor showed that the gpu temp was 62C, which seemed high, although I realize now I didn't actually check that.

Comment: @jakegould I've been trying to find a priest who doesn't use holy water. I feel as though that wouldn't end well

Comment: 62C what GPU do you have specifically?  While that is high its not high enough to cause your GPU to overheat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely causes, which you can test:

1. Loose connectors. Reseat all the cards and connectors you've intentionally moved, and any cords (including the power cord) that could have worked loose.
2. Bad bearing in HDD or fans. If the PC freezes *almost immediately* on tilting, it is more likely the HDD; if it takes a few seconds, it could be the CPU cooler fan bearing. To check the HDD, boot and run from a USB flash stick with WinPE or Linux (e.g. Ubuntu). If the PC runs in any position without using the HDD, you've isolated that issue.

BTW, I've had a primary hard drive go bad so that the PC would only boot on its side; otherwise the drive squealed and would not get up to speed. It was possible to install another HDD and recover everything before scrapping the old one (there are some great Nd magnets inside).

Comment: Just noticed I never responded to this. The issue ended up being a loose HDD cable. Reseated that properly and it was fine!

Answer (score -2):

1. All connections must be in the correct position and seated correctly
   ie: graphics card, RAM modules…
2. All connectors must be seated firmly and correctly
3. All fans and motors need to run freely and when powered up run correctly
4. Any strange sounds or intermittant sounds must be investigated
5. That the PC functions in that angle indicates one of the above could be at fault, also check for:

   - something could be making an incorect electrical connection - see if you can find it and why
   - something is not turning or running correctly, causing secondery actions to be taken by hardware and or software
   - something that you have taken apart that you should not, have is now not making the corect thermal contact and causing the chip or CPU now to over heat ie: heatsinks and fans disassembled to remove dust.